# How can I access my dispatch routines from my props using TypeScript + Redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Take a look at the following slice I've created in TypeScript (`storeSlice.ts`):

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import { AppThunk } from "../../app/store";
import { Summoner } from "../../models/Summoner";

export interface StoreState {
    summoners: Summoner[]
}

const initialState: StoreState = {
    summoners: []
}

export const storeSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'store',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        getSummonersSuccess: (state: StoreState, action: PayloadAction<Summoner[]>) => {
            state.summoners = action.payload;
        }
    }
});

export const { getSummonersSuccess } = storeSlice.actions;

export const getSummoners = (): AppThunk => (dispatch) => {
    axios.get("api/summoners").then((response) => {
        dispatch(getSummonersSuccess(response.data));
    });
}

export default storeSlice.reducer;
```

It's pretty basic. It has an initial state that is of type `StoreState` which contains an array of type `Summoner`.

Now, the component that uses this slice looks like this (`Store.tsx`):

```
import React, { Dispatch } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getSummoners, StoreState } from './storeSlice';

interface PropState {
    store: StoreState
}

const Store = (props: StoreState) => {
    console.log("store props", props); //This contains my "getSummoners" action, but I can't access it because it's not defined in "StoreState"
    return (
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: PropState) => {
    console.log("Store state", state);
    return { summoners: state.store.summoners };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
    return {
        getSummoners: dispatch(getSummoners)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Store);
```

When I log the props in the component, I get the state that I've mapped with `mapStateToProps`, and I also get the `getSummoners` action that I've mapped with `mapDispatchToProps`.

However, I cannot actually access the `getSummoners` action because it is not defined in `StoreState`.

I do not want to have to define the actions in every default state type that I create.

Is there something I can do to be able to use the dispatch actions in my code whilst keeping TypeScript happy?

Apologies if this question doesn't make too much sense, I'm fairly new to this tech stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mapDispatchToProps` you are inadvertanly calling the `dispatch` rather than returning a function to call the `dispatch` from your component.  Change it to:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
    return {
        getSummoners: () => dispatch(getSummoners)
    }
}
```

This should clear up your problems.  If it doesn't, please update your post with the exact error that you are getting.

As a sidenote, this `connect` higher-order component with `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` has been around for a while and it used to be the only way to get data from the state into your component.  It still works, but nowadays it is recommended that you use the newer hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch` instead.